# RSpec/Capybara's headless browser doesn't get stopped by html5 form required validations

Tags: ruby, html, rspec, sinatra, capybara

Technology stack - Ruby, Sinatra (RSpec, Capybara for TDD)

Whilst putting html5 validations for form inputs, I set them all as required. In Chrome browser, it would give you a popup notification saying you need to fill in the box, and thus prevent you from submitting the form.

However, in our command line tests, RSpec/Capybara would ignore these html validations and continue on, thus failing our tests.

Is there a recommended way to deal with this? Has anyone else experienced this particular problem?

Comment: I have experienced this problem. Did you ever find a solution? Going to experiment with using differing browsers other than the default.

Comment: This may be no longer an issue. I know `chromedriver` wasn't particularly robust when it first came out.

Answer (score -2):

As I understand it, the expression you used yourself "html validations" answers your own question.  These validations are different from validations specified in a testing framework.
https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape  looks like another way of doing things, but Testing frameworks are not web browsers, and that's where I see the confusion arising.

Comment: In case you are unaware the whole point of capybara is to write acceptance tests which includes client side behavior. That's why html validations being enforced would be expected in this case.